# Netcat / Apache solution to send data to PHP

Tags: php, apache, netcat

I have this device that sends XML data to a webserver in format as follows

POST HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:text/xml
Content-Length:369
Followed by XML

The problem here is that apache simply sends 400 error for this and does not work.

Is there anyway to create netcat to read xml and send to php? Any other solution welcome! Is it better to run php to listen to Port? in that case will multiple requests at the same time work?

Comment: You're not posting to a specific file in that request...

Comment: yes, that is why the 400 error comes. but the device cannot be changed so any alternate server solution is welcome.

Comment: Done and dusted.

managed to do this with socket programming on php http://www.functionblog.com/?p=67=1

All works great and ignores all errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done and dusted. managed to do this with socket programming on php functionblog.com/?p=67=1 All works great and ignores all errors with non conforming client calls as above.